# Have null repsonse in while loop

Tags: javascript, jenkins

I'm trying to get the next groupname. I know that the first one is toto.

The method DownStreamProject give me the next name.

I don't understand why I have null in my first console.log and what can I do ?

```
    function getall(groupname) {
    console.log(groupname);
    //toto
    ajaxGet(".../" + groupname + "/api/json?pretty=true", recover);
}

function ajaxGet(url, callback) {
    ...
}

function recover(response){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var Data = Json.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {    
            console.log(group.name);    
            //titi
            // Save in global state
            global.groupname = group.name;
        });          
}

global.groupname = "toto"; // start

// Assume the chain ends when groupname is null or blank
while (global.groupname) {
    // Do something with groupname
    // ...
    // reset groupname to exit if ajax call fails
    global.groupname = null;
    // Get next groupname
    getall(global.groupname); 
}
```

Actual result:

null

Eroor 404 Not found https://.../null/api

Expected result:

toto
titi
tata
trtr
tztz

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting  global.groupname to null in while loop which calls the getall() where you are logging.

Comment: Ok but how can I take the new groupname at each iteration ?